# Projectile with air resistance find time when y = 0

Tags: python

I have to find the time when **y = 0**.

I have this formula

```
y(t) = m/k(v0sinθ + mkg)(1−e^[−k/m * t])−m/k * (gt)
```

I isolated the **t** like that

```
t = [m/k(v0sinθ + mkg)(1−e^[−k/m * t]) * k] / gm
```

I already did something similar for `x=a(1− e^−x)`.

Right now I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

```
    m = 0.5
    k = 1
    v0 = 20
    theta = 25
    g = 9.8
    
    i = 1

    a = ((m/k)*(v0 * np.sin(np.deg2rad(theta)) + (m/k) * g))
    
    tolerance = 0.001

    t0 = a
   
    t1 = a * (1 - exp(- (k/m) * a)) * k / (m*g)
    
    error = t0 - t1

    while error > tolerance:
        t0 = t1
        t1 = a * (1 - exp(- (k/m) * t1)) * k / (m*g)
    
        error = t0 - t1
    
        i+=1
```

Comment: `e^x` should be `math.exp(x)` and also the exponential operator is `**`.

Comment: I forgot to mention.  I had import exp module.
from math import exp

Comment: if you are still having a trouble, edit to share the minimum, reproducible example of your issue.